# Sign in with MySite

Tags: java, authentication, web, openid

I want users will be able to sign in other sites using their accounts on my site. It should be something like "Sign in with Google". Can you advice me any libraries or frameworks? 
I thought about how to run my site as openid provider but I really don't understand it... Can you help me? I'm just a beginner in programming. I using java.

Thanks. And sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just beginning to program then this might be a bit over your head. But if you're still willing to try, then take a look at tutorials regarding writing an open id provider (like [here](http://developers-blog.org/blog/default/2010/10/01/OpenID-Tutorial-and-Java-Implementations) or [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-openid2/) ). 
Some helpful libraries are listed [here](http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995226/Run%20your%20own%20identity%20server) and [here](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/).

It is important for you to understand how open id works and one good place to start is [this google presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLsfzTNIykY).